# What do we call to someone who believes that God does not exists?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, differences

We know there are differences between,

1. One who disbelieves/denies that God does exist
2. One who believes/accepts that God does not exist

Now Dictionary.com defines the term [atheist](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/atheist) as

> **atheist** [*ey-thee-ist*]:  a person who denies or disbelieves the
>   existence of a supreme being or beings.

So, **what do we call someone who believes that God does not exist?** Is there any such word in english?

**Note:** The question came to my mind because, a person disbelieving on a premise does not necessarily need to believe on the opposite of that premise right? For example, in the above mentioned premises, someone who denies that god exists can be agnostic (a person who believes that nothing is known or can be known of the existence or nature of God) as well. But someone who believes god does not exist can not be an agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/atheism), *atheism* is:

> the belief that God does not exist.

An *atheist* is somebody who subscribes to *atheism*; thus the word you are looking for is *atheist*.

On a higher level, in English, most people consider that *disbelief* in something is equivalent to *belief* in its opposite.  This is known as [the principle of the excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle), and its status as a logical principle goes back to Aristotle. There are a few philosophers and mathematicians who do not believe in it, but these are a very small minority.

Possibly in your native language, *disbelief* and *belief* mean different things than they do in English. But the only English words I can think of that might be answers to your questions are *agnostic* and *atheist*.

Comment: Thank you Peter for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

Atheist [ey-thee-ist]

A dictionary goes 'a person who disbelieves or lacks belief in the existence of God or gods'. Stephen Hawking was an atheist, who never believed in the existence of God.

Comment: The word atheist and its definition was given in the question, I think the question was asking for a different word not so much an example of an atheist.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs exactly. My question is clear but many of the downvoters seem too hurry to get it.

Comment: So are there more than just _theists_, _atheists_ and _agnostics_? Maybe "freethinkers"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks Pal!